# ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 300

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, knn

**Help Me, please...... ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, the length must be 1: given 300**

**Splitting Data**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(feature,target, test_size=0.3,random_state=101)
```

**Modeling**

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knm = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knm.fit(xtrain,ytrain.values.ravel())
```

**Predictions**

```
Predictions = knm.predict(xtest)
```

**Conclutions**

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
print(classification_report(ytest,Predictions))
print(confusion_matrix(ytest,Predictions))
```

**Everything is ok but I got an error from here**

error_rate = []

for i in range(1,40):

```
knm = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
knm.fit(xtrain,ytrain.values.ravel())
pred_i = knm.predict(xtest)
error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != ytest))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the code you posted without problems, but given that you did not post an example of how your original dataframe looked like, it is hard to give much advice.

Based on the error message, I suspect one of your arrays have the wrong shape. Maybe try using `reshape()` to get the expected shape?